# Cron.hourly runs 17 min past the hour

Tags: linux, cron

I added a file to my cron.hourly folder. It runs every hour but it runs 17 min past the hour. So instead of running at 5:00, it runs at 5:17. How can I change the cron.hourly or reset it to exact hours.

Comment: What does your configuration look like? What OS and version are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hourly cron is triggered by another cron entry. I FC28 I have /etc/cron.d/0hourly:

```
# Run the hourly jobs
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
```

On other linux distros it might be slightly different and could be in another cron file.

Comment: This can often be confirmed by watching `/var/log/cron` , and looking for the messages which say things like `(run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)`.

Comment: sorry for sounding like a novice, how do I watch /var/log/cron?

Comment: tail -n 100 -f /var/log/cron. Location is also distro dependent

Answer (score 2):

That depends on *how* the hourly cron is configured ...

- Most conventional is that cron.hourly is scheduled from the `/etc/crontab` configuration file
- Systemd also supports [cron](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd-cron/systemd.cron.7.en.html) timers which can replace the conventional cron daemon
- And don’t forget that scripts/jobs in /etc/cron.d

And keep in mind that scripts in /etc/cron.hourly run sequentially in lexicographical order and if `a-script` starts on the hour and takes 17 minutes then `b-script` will start only 17 minutes past the hour